# Is this condition is wrong or the comparison?

Tags: python

For any argument I pass, the result is wrong input only

script.py:-

```
    try:
        command_line = sys.argv[1].strip()
    except IndexError:
        print "\n***PLEASE READ THE HEADER NOTE FOR RUNNING THIS PROGRAM***\n"
        exit(1)

    if command_line != "run" or command_line != "fullrun":
        print "\n***WRONG INPUT, PLEASE READ THE HEADER NOTE FOR RUNNING THIS\
 PROGRAM***\n"
        exit(1)
```

output:-

```
$script.py run

***WRONG INPUT, PLEASE READ THE HEADER NOTE FOR RUNNING THIS PROGRAM***
```

What is wrong with the comparison or condition?

Comment: `command_line != "fullrun"` is true, therefore `command_line != "run" or command_line != "fullrun"` is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your boolean logic wrong. Use `and`:

```
if command_line != "run" and command_line != "fullrun":
```

You are saying that if the user did not enter `run` **or** they did not enter `fullrun`, the command is wrong. But if I enter `run` I didn't enter `fullrun` and vice versa, making one of the two conditions *always true*.

You may want to use `not in` and a set instead:

```
if command_line not in {"run", "fullrun"}:
```

This is a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks man, it was the silliest one. I need a break indeed!

Answer (score 1):

> if command_line != "run" and command_line != "fullrun":

will work better! :-)

You are using or but either condition will always be true in such case.

Also, I suggest you take a look at the argparse module which will help you to make nicely featured arguments handling and help summaries.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: I was a fool. Thanks my condition was true for any value